# Is there any way to import issue history in JIRA using CSV importer

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

JIRA CSV Importer: I want to import issue with it's history in Jira using csv.
Is there any way to import issue history in JIRA using CSV importer plugin?Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON importer supports issue history but the CSV importer does not.